# Elasticsearch Using the Attachment Processor in a Pipeline doesn't remove images from files

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using the Attachment Processor in a Pipeline defined as:

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/attachment

{
  "description": "Extract attachment information",
  "processors": [
    {
      "foreach": {
        "field": "attachments",
        "processor": {
          "attachment": {
            "field": "_ingest._value.data",
            "target_field": "_ingest._value.attachment",
            "properties": [ "content" ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
     "foreach": {
        "field": "attachments",
        "processor" : {
            "remove" : { "field" : "_ingest._value.data" }
          }
        }
     }  
  ]
}
```

EXPECTED:

Given a set of attachments, with different file types, such as doc, Docx, or pdf, those files will be processed (by Tika) to get the raw text, where table layouts, font type, font colors and IMAGES  will be removed.

But it looks like the images are still there after ingestion. I can see some very long base64 strings into the content field, like

lWQk9SdzBLR2dvQUFBQU5TVWhFVWdBQUFQb0FBQUQ2Q0FZQUFBQ0k3Rm85QUFBZ0FFbEVRVlI0WGx5OUI1TWNXWEtsNjVGYWxBWlFBQnBvTVQz...

which I believe, are related to images into the files.

Any suggestions for getting rid of the images?

Answer (score 1):

Could not replicate. I installed the plugin via `bin/elasticsearch-plugin install ingest-attachment` and exported a simple document into PDF and DOCX:

[image]

The PDF converted into base64 is [in this gist](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jzzfs/21cd42f2679455e3e02039805a76d886/raw/af60b09822284f3291d5a7ace5c08846af2d6636/b64-pdf.txt), the the DOCX [here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jzzfs/b1fd918d6ac84d199e5aeaec64e02e86/raw/23e3b8281328eaf8a8fc5b29877c06f223c7a881/b64-docx.txt).

Running

```json
PUT my-index-000001/_doc/1?pipeline=attachment
{
  "attachments": [
    {
      "data": "pdf-base64-txt..."
    },
    {
      "data": "docx-base64-txt..."
    }
  ]
}
```

correctly removed the images and left only the text.

As such,

```json
GET my-index-000001/_search
```

resulted in

```json
{
  "_index" : "my-index-000001",
  "_type" : "_doc",
  "_id" : "1",
  "_score" : 1.0,
  "_source" : {
    "attachments" : [
      {
        "attachment" : {
          "content" : "Some text"
        }
      },
      {
        "attachment" : {
          "content" : "Some text"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Neither do I, to be honest. I have this situation with a part of a dataset that come from documents that are  created with an online resume builder ( paid service ).  So ( I think ) this tool converts html to pdf, and embed images and other data in the document directly as base64 data. Then this is definitively not related to elasticsearch. What do you think? Have you ever encountered with this kind of situation?

Comment: If the circumstances permit, can you share the b64 content in a github gist?

Comment: Ok a fake example [here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/olographic/39b1df13a6f2ac0d3d021caf58c4f25e/raw/9289b7d547b0c468c070e20c6a0501dbd5df674b/example)

Comment: [Here's my result](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jzzfs/9dca8c25f6f7ee4641ae1e1d150bc3d1/raw/6b782a37cd95695655911098def1906fe60558af/pipeline-result.txt). The original b64 may or may not be malformed... Not sure. You could add one more pipeline processor and remove particularly long strings with a regex or something.

Answer (score 1):

In the end I decided for something like this, and remove long strings as suggested
by Joe Sorocin

```
{
  "description": "Extract attachment information",

  "processors": [
    {
      "foreach": {
        "field": "attachments",
        "processor": {
          "attachment": {
            "field": "_ingest._value.data",
            "target_field": "_ingest._value.attachment",
            "properties": [ "content" ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
  {
         "foreach": {
        "field": "attachments",
        "processor" : {
            "remove" : { "field" : "_ingest._value.data" }
          }
        }
     },
     {
         "foreach": {
             "field": "attachments",
             "processor": {
                 "gsub": {
                     "field": "_ingest._value.attachment.content",
                     "pattern": "[a-z|A-Z|0-9|+|\/]{100,}",
                     "replacement":""
                     }
             }
         }
     }  
  ]
}
```